After filing a provisional application, is the USPTO supposed to send you something either mail or email?
I've filed a provisional with the USPTO.
Afterwards, the application number and other info appeared on the screen and I was able to search and find the application with the application number using the Patent Center.
But I have not received anything in the mail or email.
Am I supposed to?
EDIT:
Also, the filing date is blank.
I only see a receipt date / time, but no filing date or priority date. Is that normal?

How long ago did you file? IIRC filing date is not instantaneous as they must check for missing parts.

I filed last night. How can they check for missing parts without looking at the content of my provisional?

They will take a cursory look at the content of every filed provisional.

How long does it take for them to complete this examination of missing parts? Will the filing date be the date that I filed?

Yes, the filing date should be retroactively the date that you filed, once it is accorded. For the first question I don't really know but it shouldn't be longer than a few business days I guess.

Immediately after filing any application with the USPTO you will receive an Electronic Acknowledgement Receipt. This is a more of an "unofficial" Filing Receipt. It will not include a Filing Date. Provisional applications for patent cannot claim the benefit of a previously-filed application, either foreign or domestic.
After filing any application with the USPTO, you will receive a Filing Receipt. The Filing Receipt will include all of the Official metadata for your application: Applicant, Inventor Name, Confirmation Number, Power of Attorney, Document Exchange permission, your Foreign Filing License, your (provisional) application number, entity status, Application Title, and the like.
It may take a couple of weeks to get the Filing Receipt. For example, I filed a Provisional Application on 9/16/2024 and received the Filing Receipt 10/2/2024.
It is important to review the Filing Receipt for accuracy. If there are any typos or mistakes, you should find the procedures to correct, if the errors are correctable.
You can review the MPEP Section 503 for more information:
https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s503.html
